# Plot of the image of a circle by some functions

Tags: plotting, complex

Consider the set $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z-1|<\frac{1}{4}\}$

I would like to plot the image of $A$ under the function $f(z)=z^{2}$, and in a different plot, the image of $A$ under the function $g(z)=(z-1)^{2}(z+1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ParametricPlot[]` with the alternate parametric representation $1+r\exp(it),\quad 0<r<\frac14,\, 0<t<2\pi$, we can do this:

```
f[z_] := z^2;
g[z_] := (z - 1)^2 (z + 1)

{ParametricPlot[ReIm[1 + r E^(I t)], {r, 0, 1/4}, {t, 0, 2 π}], 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[f[1 + r E^(I t)]], {r, 0, 1/4}, {t, 0, 2 π}], 
 ParametricPlot[ReIm[g[1 + r E^(I t)]], {r, 0, 1/4}, {t, 0, 2 π}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: a disk and some of its images]

Answer (score 3):

Here's the first one... writing z as x+Iy, define the function f[z] and then use RegionFunction to define the set:

```
f[x_, y_] := {Re[(x + I y)^2], Im[(x + I y)^2]}; 
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Abs[x^2 + y^2 - 1] < 1/4]]
```

Then do the same for

```
g[x_, y_] := {Re[(x + I y -1)^2 (x + I y +1)], Im[(x + I y -1)^2 (x + I y +1)]};
```

[image]

Comment: But the plots cant be 3D, I asked for the image of the set, it should be a plot on the complex plane. And in the first case, the plot can't have elements with negative real part.
Just think about the angle of any element that is in the set $A$ and what happen to that element when yo take the square.